# Is it secure to get new csrf hash token from ajax response?

Tags: php, security, zend-framework, csrf, csrf-protection

I use zend 1 framework and I have form that use ajax multiple time, I secured it with csrf, but after first request csrf token will expire and I need new One. Is it secure to pass new csrf token from server side and use it in front side for new ajax call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a rolling CSRF token is always a bad design because if the user has multiple windows open then a race condition occurs on which CSRF token is currently valid.

When implementing any security system try and use an existing library or a well documented technique. Don't shoot from the hip, read the [CSRF prevention Cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

A rotating CSRF token does not improve security because the same bypass techniques will always obtain the current CSRF token.  All CSRF mitigations rely upon the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) - and if your application has a SOP bypass - such as a weak crossdomain.xml file or an insecure CORS ruleset, or XSS - then an attacker can use this vulnerability to read **any HTTP response**. For any given web application some HTTP response must have the CSRF token, and an SOP bypass can be used to read this token and forge interactions between the browser and web application.

It doesn't matter what type of CSRF mitigation is in place - XSS can always be used to force the browser into performing any action that the user can perform.  If a request that is vulnerability to reflective XSS, also requires a CSRF token then it will be very difficult or impossible to exploit.  For this reason, CSRF & XSS have a kind of rock paper scissors relationship.

Answer (score -1):

If you're experiencing problems with the anti-forgery token behaviours, have you thought about using the SameSite cookies flag instead?

Long story short. When you send a cross-origin request (for example, site A sending a request to site B), your browser will be kind enough to also check if you have cookies for that site, and thus, you can be vulnerable to a XSRF attack. We use the anti-forgery tokens to create a shared secret between a valid entity sending a request, and the server. But as you can see, there can be some problems with the implementation.

On the other hand, the same-site cookie flag allows you to configure how your cookies will be sent via cross-origin requests. There are two modes, the strict mode and the lax mode.

In strict mode, your cookies will never be sent via cross-origin requests. This can seem like a great approach, but you also need to consider that the cookies will not be send via GET requests, so if someone gets redirected to your site, he'll need to login again, because the cookies were not sent in that request.

The lax mode does almost the same, but it allows your cookies to be sent via safe HTTP verbs (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS and TRACE), so you'll keep a defense against POST/PUT CSRF attacks, but you'll still get a nice behaviour with users browsing via GET requests.

**Edit:** Just adding that even when the SameSite cookie flag sounds like a really good option, it has only been implemented by Chrome and Opera, so if your user-base are people using all kinds of different browsers and different versions, it not might be the best option for your app.

Comment: -1 SameSite is an RFC draft, it is not supported by all browsers, and centennially not ready for production.  I'll remove the -1 in 5 years when it is in common use.

Comment: @rook Gotta give you that point, I forgot to clarify that at least for now, the SameSite cookie flag has only been implemented by Chrome and Opera.